# How to retrieve displayed text from activex explorer?

Tags: autohotkey, activex

; Too long and I thought no need to be shown in this post.

```
Gui Add, ActiveX, w400 h225 vWB, Shell.Explorer
URL := certain url
WB.Navigate(URL)
ComObjConnect( 
Gui Show,
```

I barely know about com and try to search any helpful information via web.
The thing is that Explorer shown above can be controlled via com, as far as I know. So I have tried to find a way to retrieve the shown text, not the source code inside. I think there must be a way, but for me it's hard. Hope anybody gives me a tip or solution, please.

Comment: something like wb.document.documentelement.outerhtml looks helpful but it just gives me whole text including source code.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use PowerShell to discover how to do things involving COM objects before doing them with Autohotkey.

Example:

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
# Show the available members of the object
$ie | gm
$ie.Visible = $true
$ie.Navigate("www.google.com")
# This should show you all you can do on the document object
$ie.Document | gm
```

That said the ActiveX control in the GUI isn't a 'InternetExplorer.Application' so it's a little different. You can open the same type with something like https://adminscache.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/open-web-browser-in-powershell-gui/.

Anyway here is a working example, it took me a long time!

```
; https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/93660-embedded-ie-shellexplorer-render-issues-fix-force-it-to-use-a-newer-render-engine/
FixIE(Version=0, ExeName="")
{
    static Key := "Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer"
    . "\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION"
    , Versions := {7:7000, 8:8888, 9:9999, 10:10001, 11:11001}
    
    if Versions.HasKey(Version)
        Version := Versions[Version]
    
    if !ExeName
    {
        if A_IsCompiled
            ExeName := A_ScriptName
        else
            SplitPath, A_AhkPath, ExeName
    }
    
    RegRead, PreviousValue, HKCU, %Key%, %ExeName%
    if (Version = "")
        RegDelete, HKCU, %Key%, %ExeName%
    else
        RegWrite, REG_DWORD, HKCU, %Key%, %ExeName%, %Version%
    return PreviousValue
}

FixIE()
Gui Add, ActiveX, w400 h225 vWB hwndTest, Shell.Explorer
URL := "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey"
WB.Navigate(URL)
ComObjConnect(WB)
Gui Show, 
while, WB.ReadyState < 4
    Sleep, 10

jtest := "var r = document.createRange();r.selectNode(document.body);window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();window.getSelection().addRange(r);document.body.setAttribute('ahk', window.getSelection().toString().trim());window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();"
WB.document.parentwindow.execScript(jtest)
MsgBox, % WB.document.body.getAttribute("ahk")
return


GuiClose:
ExitApp
```

Reference: https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/93660-embedded-ie-shellexplorer-render-issues-fix-force-it-to-use-a-newer-render-engine/

The key was using the JavaScript to get the text, it will be easier to get the text of a specific element, just use the getElementById or something like that.